# How to copy file to output directory on every change during debugging

Tags: visual-studio, file-management

In item's properties there is **Copy to Output Directory** option which copies a file after build. However the files I want to copy to output are very often data that can be reloaded by the program dynamically **at runtime** so I would like to be able to replace them on every save during debugging, while still keeping them in solution explorer.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I imagine few option

- Some existing VS extension can do this, ideal
- Write new extension, which will probably need some extensive research for me. Can't estimate time needed to do this
- Write some simple external program, which will be annoying to setup in long run

Answer (score 1):

I have a sample extension for [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) demonstrating how to hook the save event in Visual Studio: [Run Cppcheck on the saved file](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/extensions.html#OnDocumentSaved).

So, you just need to add a filter condition to the OnDocumentSaved method and copy the saved file to the output directory.